# Trouble translating a line (shape)

Tags: java, line, shapes

For an assignment we were asked to modify existing code to include more than one shape, more than one color, and to have the shapes move. I got a little carried away and started adding in more things but now we have an issue. All was going well until I added the left arm(as viewed on the screen). I am having a problem with a piece of the arm remaining in the previous place when moving the figure to the right. Up, down, and left are all working well, it is only to the right where I hit the problem. I have added a screenshot of what it looks like after I move the figures to the right two times. Thanks for any assistance you may be able to provide.
[roboMan output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8fGG.png)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;  

public class SwingBot1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // contruction of new JFrame object
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    // mutators
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setTitle("SwingBot");

    // program ends when window closes
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Robot r = new Robot();

    frame.add(r);

    // voila!
    frame.setVisible(true);


    // your Scanner-based command loop goes here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean active = true;
    while(active){
        System.out.println("Enter \"up\", \"down\", \"left\", or  \"right\" "
                + "to move.\nClose the window to quit.");
        String direction = in.nextLine();
        switch(direction){
        case "up":
            r.moveBot(0, -20);
            break;
        case "down":
            r.moveBot(0, 20);
            break;
        case "right":
            r.moveBot(20, 0);
            break;
        case "left":
            r.moveBot(-20, 0);
            break;

        }
    }
}
public static class Robot extends JComponent
{
    private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(45, 30, 20, 20);

    int x = 30;
    int y = 50;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        // set the color
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        // draw the shape`
        g2.fill(rect);

        Graphics2D g3 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g3.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g3.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(30, 50, 50, 100));
        g3.fillOval(30, 50, 50, 100);

        Graphics2D g4 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g4.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g4.draw(new Line2D.Double(70, 141, 90, 190));
        g4.draw(new Line2D.Double(39, 141, 30, 191));

        Graphics2D g5 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g5.setColor(Color.RED);
        g5.draw(new Line2D.Double(80, 85, 125, 70));

        //arm, left as viewed
        g5.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 70, 30, 85));


    }


    public void moveBot(int x, int y)
    {
        setX(getX()+x);
        setY(getY()+y);
        repaint();
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
    /*  public void moveBot(int x, int y)
    {
        // move the rectangle 
        rect.translate(x,y);
        // redraw the window
        poly.translate(x, y);
        repaint();

    }*/

  }
}
```

Comment: try repainting the frame.

Comment: @Taylor Thank you, that worked perfectly.

Comment: I'll re-add as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to repaint the frame.